# Using convert in a select statement for Jasper Reports

Tags: sql, oracle11g, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm trying to retrieve some data (String) from a database, and perform some actions on them that would require them to be converted to `DateTime`.

First off, though, I'd like to know if it is possible to pull data of type `String` from the Database, Convert them into `DateTime`, and then use them in a report.

I can't change the database, unfortunately, which I believe would help greatly.

So I looked up convert commands, and came up with this:

```
(convert(datetime[10], fld7, 101))
```

Which is used here (as DTEEEFFEC):

```
SELECT fld2 as EMPNAME, fld5 as EMPCLASSFROM, 
       fld6 as EMPCLASSTO, (convert(datetime[10], fld7, 101)) as DTEEFFEC,
       (b.LNAME  || ', ' || b.FNAME  || ' ' || b.MNAME) AS HROFF 
FROM dbase.table1 
    LEFT JOIN dbase.person_info ON $P{hrStoreOp}= b.ID_PERSONAL
WHERE compname = $P{COMPNAME} order by fld7,fld2 asc
```

It returns an error, though: *missing right parenthesis*, or, if I remove the brackets and the 10, this one: *"DATETIME": invalid identifier*

Edit: I'm so sorry I left this out, but does using an Oracle Database mean anything? I thought they both use similar SQL statements.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. How do I change the text colors on selected items so I can do it myself in the future?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

```
 SELECT fld2 as EMPNAME, fld5 as EMPCLASSFROM, 
   fld6 as EMPCLASSTO, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),fld7, 101) as DTEEFFEC,
   (b.LNAME  || ', ' || b.FNAME  || ' ' || b.MNAME) AS HROFF 
 FROM dbase.table1 
   LEFT JOIN dbase.person_info ON $P{hrStoreOp}= b.ID_PERSONAL
 WHERE compname = $P{COMPNAME} order by fld7,fld2 asc
```

Comment: It gave me an error: ORA-00936: missing expression. Also, I edited my code above; I typed out one that would obviously give out an error.

Comment: at the place of VARCHAR(10) in function CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),fld7, 101) you have to use datatype of fld7 column

Comment: DateTime(10) and String(10) gets me an invalid identifier.